When I was trying to create a test using JUnit test for Java I got the following error:
Project junit-team-junit5-12e9d92:  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'junitbuild.build-parameters'] Failed to apply plugin 'junitbuild.build-parameters'. Unknown build parameter: nbSerializeCheck (settings.gradle.kts:10):  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'junitbuild.build-parameters'] Failed to apply plugin 'junitbuild.build-parameters'. Unknown build parameter: nbSerializeCheck (settings.gradle.kts:10)

I tried to fix it by deleting some of the files and trying to see if there is any error with the code. But nothing worked

That's hard to answer without having more information, e.g your test setup, your tests, etc. - The only advice I can give atm is to google this error.

I use VS Code IDE and I did not start testing at all. This error appeared in VS Code while startup. The iDE could not load the libraries and packages associated with JUnit

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

First of all, you need to provide more of your code to help find out the problem.
Now, based on your error you can check the following conditions. Might be your problem will be solved:

Check junitbuild.build-parameters plugin Version, Ensure that you are using a compatible version of the junitbuild.build-parameters plugin for your project setup.
Check nbSerializeCheck in the project files to see if it is defined anywhere (such as in build scripts, configuration files, or plugins). If it’s missing or incorrect, you can define it properly or remove it if not required.
Ensure that the Gradle version and all related plugins are up to date.
If you’re using a specific version of JUnit from GitHub repository, check the build documentation for any required parameters or updated build configurations.

